# Función factorial sin decimales

Tags: r, factorial

Tengo que hacer una función con la cual pueda calcular el factorial de un numero pero que al colocar algún número negativo o que no se entero (decimal o fracción) el resultado sea un mensaje de error, hasta ahora he podido hacer esto:

```
factorial<-function(n){
resultado=1
while(n>0){
    resultado<-resultado*n
    n<-n-1
}
if(n<0){
    resultado="Error"
}
return(resultado)
```

}

Sin embargo no se como condicionar a la función para que me mande el mensaje de error cuando ponga el número no entero.

Answer (score 1):

Para determinar si un número es entero, lo más sencillo es obtener el resto de la división por `1`, así:

```
1.6%%1==0
[FALSE]
6%%1==0, 
[TRUE]
```

Retornar un error es algo ambiguo como definición, el retorno de una función es único, en tu caso, retorna  un entero, por lo que no es correcto devolver una cadena en el caso del error, podrías sí, retornar un valor que no pueda darse con un funcionamiento normal, por ejemplo -1. Tu función quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
factorial<-function(n){

    if (n < 0 || n%%1 != 0) { return(-1) }

    resultado <- 1
    while( n > 0 ){
        resultado<-resultado*n
        n <- n-1
    }
    return(resultado)
}
```

Con estos retornos de ejemplo:

```
> factorial(3)
[1] 6
> factorial(-2)
[1] -1
> factorial(4.5)
[1] -1
```

La otra posibilidad ya te la han mencionado, es el uso del [`stop()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/stop.html), con esta función puedes "emitir" un mensaje personalizado, pero tienes que tener en cuenta que eventualmente detiene la ejecución del script completo.

Answer (score 0):

Podés usar la función stop de la siguiente manera:

```
factorial <- function(n){
  if(n < 0){
    stop('n debe ser positivo')
  } else if(n != round(n)){
    stop('n debe ser entero')
  } else {
    resultado=1
    while(n>0){
      resultado<-resultado*n
      n<-n-1
    }
    return(resultado)
  } 
}
```

La función stop detiene la ejecución de la función que estamos definiendo, por eso es necesario chequear los casos de error antes de calcular el factorial.